# How can I get np.nditer's operands in jitted numba functions?

Tags: python, numpy, numba, array-broadcasting

For example (from https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html):

```
def iter_add_py(x, y, out=None):
    addop = np.add
    it = np.nditer([x, y, out], [],
        [['readonly'], ['readonly'], ['writeonly','allocate']])
    with it:
        for (a, b, c) in it:
            addop(a, b, out=c)
        return it.operands[2]
```

In the case out = None, the only way to access the result of the operation is with it.operands[2].  Numba's nditer supports None as an operand, creating the correct empty array, but it's inaccessible because Numba doesn't support the operands attribute.  Speed is critical in my solution.

Things I've tried:

- Sending a new empty array (which we can reference) into out is a seemingly obvious solution, but you'd need to manually compute the broadcasted shape, dtype, etc.  I couldn't find a way to do this, with/without numpy, that was quick enough to justify ignoring that nditer does the job anyway.
- Even if I could, Numba's nditer doesn't support flags in its constructor, rendering it read-only, so the best way I could find to fill the array is to enumerate nditer and set out.flat in the loop, which is also too slow (and a little gross).
- Unsurprisingly, a jitted function can't return nor take nditer objects.  I'm new to Numba, so I could be wrong about this, but I couldn't find anything to the contrary.  I can only iterate inside the function.
- There's no Numba support for np.broadcast, so that won't work.
- I should mention that Numba.vectorize isn't an option, for a host of irrelevant reasons.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to use `nditer`?  With those 'flags', that function just does `x+y`.  Are you trying to do something with `nditer` that can't be done directly with operators, or "raw" `numba` iteration?  I haven't been impressed with `nditer` when used in Python code, though I used it a bit to simulate `np.einsum` in `cython` code (years ago) (see this page: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.nditer.html)

Comment: @hpaulj Exactly, I'm trying to do something that can't be done directly with operators or Numba.  I've been up and down that page a million times, and am considering throwing away my Numba work thus far in favor of Cython.

Comment: may be helpful relating to broadcasting: https://github.com/numba/numba/pull/7119  &  
https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/7467

Comment: I do not understand either why need to use `nditer`, especially if you care about performance. Why not using plain loops (that are very fast)? Can you provide a practical use of `iter_add_py`?

Comment: @JérômeRichard In essence I need to implement a bunch of performant vectorized operations with multiple outputs.  This isn't possible with nb.vectorize, and guvectorize is slow.